# Checking validity of a number as a code point in ICU

Tags: c++, icu

I am playing with ICU and trying to write some classes around it. One of them is representing a code point. While I am about to write a constructor receiving a number, I would like to check wheter that number is valid as a code point.

Unfortunatelly I could not found a way in ICU to check the validity of a given UChar32 representing a code unit. ICU does return such type in some functions and does accept such UChar32 in some functions, but how can it be sure that we will not give it an invalid value?

I think there must be some validity check somewhere. Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need a class to represent a codepoint?

Comment: You could try and normalize it and see if that succeeds. It should fail for a non-Unicode value.

Comment: I dont need the class on demand, for now it is just a general purpose class, containing related functionalities like u_charDigitValue, u_getNumericValue, u_charName, u_isIDStart, etc...

Comment: Normalizing might help as well as converting to UnicodeString but seems a bit expensive as I am checking to neccessary api calls.

Comment: I feel like this is the maxiumum I can get about the topic: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr22/tr22-2.1.html. See especially Section 2.6 / Error Conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missed this one before.

`#include <unicode/uchar.h>`

- Valid (in-Unicode) `UChar32`s will be between `UCHAR_MIN_VALUE` and `UCHAR_MAX_VALUE` inclusively
- Assigned (as opposed to unassigned) `UChar32`s will evaulate false for `(u_charType(ch) != U_UNASSIGNED)`

Comment: > U_UNASSIGNED  
> See note !!.
> Comments of the form "Cn" are read by genpname. Non-category for unassigned and non-character code points.

Comment: Nice idea. Thank you! However, the documentaqtion says: "U_UNASSIGNED  : Comments of the form "Cn" are read by genpname. Non-category for unassigned and non-character code points.". So this trick is good for checking if the UChar32 number is representing a unicode character, but does not say yes for non character code points.

Comment: "The illegal code points are: out-of-range values (less than zero or greater than 10FFFF), unpaired surrogate values (D800 to DF00), and non-character values (of the form xxFFFF or xxFFFE)." I feel like my answer was wrong. The non-character is also illegal value based on this documentation.

Comment: @Peter U+FFFE, U+FFFF, U+10FFFF, will all return U_UNASSIGNED.  Surrogates will return U_SURROGATE.  So again, I think u_charType will give you all you need.